# Как удалить public/ из url в laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Вышла новая версия лары и появились новые проблемы. Поставил ее и никак не могу убрать public/ из урла, перечитал уже много статей, старые способы не работают, а в .htaccess не разбираюсь, помогите, кто уже решил эту проблему, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите в настройках `nginx/apache` сайта путь до `laravel/public/` тем самым автоматом пропадет `public/`

Answer (score 1):

Есть информация в [официальной документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#pretty-urls) по этому поводу:

Если у вас Apache:

Создайте файл `.htaccess` в папке `public` с таким содержимым:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Если Nginx:

В конфиг дописать:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Переименуйте файл `server.php` В корневой директории Laravel в `index.php` и копируйте файл `.htaccess` из папки `/public` в корневую директорию с Laravel.